# What are java web application deployment formats?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, deployment, web-deployment

WAR file is one of the common ways to deploy a java web application. What other deployments formats available for Java Web Applications? What are the differences between them?

Comment: Not a standard format _per se,_ but quite simple and easy to set up & deploy: http://dropwizard.codahale.com

Comment: From the official Java EE 6 documentation: [Packaging Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html)

Answer (score 1):

Besides `WAR`, the enterprise applications can be wrapped within the so called "enterprise archive", which extension is `ear`. Here's a list of the archive types, in which the different pieces of a web-application are wrapped.

`JAR`: EJB modules which contain enterprise java beans class files and EJB deployment descriptor are packed as JAR file(s) with `.jar` extenstion

`WAR`: Web modules which contains Servlet class files, JSP Files, supporting files, GIF and HTML files are packaged as JAR file with `.war` (web achive) extension

`EAR`: All above files(`.jar` and `.war`) are packaged as JAR file with `.ear` ( enterprise archive) extension and deployed into Application Server. Contains also third party libraries. Has a special directory called `APP-INF` that contains the `application.xml` file descriptor.